# MySQL how to get file path of blob data?

Tags: mysql, url, blob, imageurl

Im wondering is it possible to get the file path of an image or video data stored as blob in a MySQL database. I simply uploaded a video file through phpMyAdmin to my database and I need to know the url address of the video file.

Comment: Obviously, if the database *actually contains(!) the video data,* e.g. "stored as a BLOB," then there would be nothing else in the database to tell you where these data *came from,* unless the logic which stored the data into the database made some separate record of it.

Comment: Do you mean, knowing that a blob is saved not in the datapages of the table, that you want to get to it from the outside, and manipulate it somehow? Perhaps what you should do is *not* save it as a blob, but as a file reference at the o/s. I for one think blobs are junk

Comment: Mike Robinson, as far as i know, MySQL stores a reference of the blob data  in the table and saves actual file to somewhere in the server. I need to know the actual place of the data.